# ConcurrentMessageDigest Class Not Found Exception

Tags: tomcat, spring-websocket

I am using spring websocket by extending TextWebSocketHandler and HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor classes. There is no issue with websocket by using downloaded tomcat (version 7.0.55). But using tomcat as a service (version 7.0.52), in ubuntu (installed from apt-get), I got following issue during server startup.

> ERROR DispatcherServlet:492 - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean ......

After some searching, it's been found that I've to use tomcat-embed-websocket.jar and downloaded ***tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.68.jar***  and copied to project lib folder. Server start up was successful. But following issue occurred when tried to establish websocket connection. It says ***Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.security.ConcurrentMessageDigest***.

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/security/ConcurrentMessageDigest at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest...

Cant find out the solution. Please help.

Comment: Am I invisible...!

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like your tomcat7 instance has lower version than the lib you use (**tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.68.jar**).

Try to download precisely the same version of tomcat:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/7.0.68/

Comment: It's old question. Sorry i'm not able to test it now. Didn't solve that issue back then. Will try your suggestion next time. Thanks!